# Can my health care proxy make decisions over the phone?

Tags: health

I'm planning on setting up [healthcare proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Healthcare_proxy) paperwork, and trying to decide who to pick. I'm in the US, and the person I'd like to pick is in England and can't travel easily. I know it'll be harder for her to get all the relevant information without being at the hospital, but assuming I'm all right with that: will she be allowed to make medical decisions for me over the phone, or does this have to be done in person? Could a doctor legally refuse to listen to my health proxy over the phone?

Comment: You are going to get a proxy and you can't ask this of the lawyer who is going to prepare it?

Comment: I think you are going to find a collision of the legality of the thing and medical ethics. Will a doctor follow the directions of a proxy who is not available for independent evaluation of the proxy's sanity?  More to the point, do you really want your doctor taking your tubes  out based on the decision of your friend who might have just fallen on her head? All of the dr's avenues for refusing patient wishes will apply to any proxy.

Comment: @DaleM According to my medical center I can just download the form, fill it out and get it signed by two witnesses and/or notarized, and a lawyer doesn't have to be involved in preparing it. Are they wrong?

Comment: @jqning Well, I'd rather have a doctor taking tubes out based on the decision of my friend even with the small chance that she just fell on her head, than based on the decision of some local friend who I don't entirely trust. Neither's perfect, but it's what I have to work with. Is there a high chance the doctor won't do it, in practice? (I suppose that part is more of a health.se question than a law.se one)

Comment: @weronika what state do you live in?

Comment: @jqning California.